# Error in parsing a json file in R

Tags: r, json

Yelp business data with 100 instances, in the following format:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aab338ffc08b46adb7a2320"), 
    "business_id" : "Pd52CjgyEU3Rb8co6QfTPw", 
    "name" : "Flight Deck Bar & Grill", 
    "neighborhood" : "Southeast", 
    "address" : "6730 S Las Vegas Blvd", 
    "city" : "Las Vegas", 
    "state" : "NV", 
    "postal_code" : "89119", 
    "latitude" : 36.0669136, 
    "longitude" : -115.1708484, 
    "stars" : 4.0, 
    "review_count" : NumberInt(13), 
    "is_open" : NumberInt(1), 
    "attributes" : {
        "Alcohol" : "full_bar", 
        "HasTV" : true, 
        "NoiseLevel" : "average", 
        "RestaurantsAttire" : "casual", 
        "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards" : true, 
        "Music" : {
            "dj" : false, 
            "background_music" : true, 
            "no_music" : false, 
            "karaoke" : false, 
            "live" : false, 
            "video" : false, 
            "jukebox" : false
        }, 
        "Ambience" : {
            "romantic" : false, 
            "intimate" : false, 
            "classy" : false, 
            "hipster" : false, 
            "divey" : false, 
            "touristy" : false, 
            "trendy" : false, 
            "upscale" : false, 
            "casual" : true
        }, 
        "RestaurantsGoodForGroups" : true, 
        "Caters" : true, 
        "WiFi" : "free", 
        "RestaurantsReservations" : false, 
        "RestaurantsTableService" : true, 
        "RestaurantsTakeOut" : true, 
        "GoodForKids" : true, 
        "HappyHour" : true, 
        "GoodForDancing" : false, 
        "BikeParking" : true, 
        "OutdoorSeating" : false, 
        "RestaurantsPriceRange2" : NumberInt(2), 
        "RestaurantsDelivery" : false, 
        "BestNights" : {
            "monday" : false, 
            "tuesday" : false, 
            "friday" : false, 
            "wednesday" : true, 
            "thursday" : false, 
            "sunday" : false, 
            "saturday" : false
        }, 
        "GoodForMeal" : {
            "dessert" : false, 
            "latenight" : false, 
            "lunch" : true, 
            "dinner" : false, 
            "breakfast" : false, 
            "brunch" : false
        }, 
        "BusinessParking" : {
            "garage" : false, 
            "street" : false, 
            "validated" : false, 
            "lot" : true, 
            "valet" : false
        }, 
        "CoatCheck" : false, 
        "Smoking" : "no", 
        "WheelchairAccessible" : true
    }, 
    "categories" : [
        "Nightlife", 
        "Bars", 
        "Barbeque", 
        "Sports Bars", 
        "American (New)", 
        "Restaurants"
    ], 
    "hours" : {
        "Monday" : "8:30-22:30", 
        "Tuesday" : "8:30-22:30", 
        "Friday" : "8:30-22:30", 
        "Wednesday" : "8:30-22:30", 
        "Thursday" : "8:30-22:30", 
        "Sunday" : "8:30-22:30", 
        "Saturday" : "8:30-22:30"
    }
}
```

I need to import this in R. I have the following code:

```
library('jsonlite')
data<- stream_in(file("~/Desktop/business100.json"))
```

When i use the above code,It gives the following error:

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                         {     "_id" : ObjectId("5aab338ffc08b46adb7a2
                     (right here) ------^
```

I think there is some problem with the format of the json, but when i see the json file in mongodb, it looks fine. What can be done for it, thank you!

Comment: Query mongodb directly using `mongolite`

Comment: To expand a bit on @SymbolixAU'S comment, you have a MongoDB _extended JSON_ file, not a proper JSON file. (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) You'll need to import it into MongoDB to use it (that's the easiest route) or re-export it in strict mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is `mongolite` (as suggested in the comments), that is likely the best way to go. If you are stuck and cannot use it for some reason, it is possible to replace these non-JSON properties and parse it with regular JSON parsers.

To generalize, create a vector of the (verbatim) strings. I make the assumption that each property is of the form `DiscardableProperty(save_all_here)`, so a good starting point based on the data you've provided is:

```
ptns <- c('ObjectId', 'NumberInt')
str(jsontxt)
#  chr "{ \n    \"_id\" : ObjectId(\"5aab338ffc08b46adb7a2320\"), \n    \"business_id\" : \"Pd52CjgyEU3Rb8co6QfTPw\", \n    \"name\" : "| __truncated__
jsontxt2 <- Reduce(function(txt, p) gsub(sprintf("%s\\(([^)]+)\\)", p), "\\1", txt),
                   ptns, init=jsontxt)
str(jsontxt2)
#  chr "{ \n    \"_id\" : \"5aab338ffc08b46adb7a2320\", \n    \"business_id\" : \"Pd52CjgyEU3Rb8co6QfTPw\", \n    \"name\" : \"Flight D"| __truncated__
```

(Notice the absence of `ObjectId`.)

This parses just fine:

```
str(fromJSON(jsontxt2))
# List of 16
#  $ _id         : chr "5aab338ffc08b46adb7a2320"
#  $ business_id : chr "Pd52CjgyEU3Rb8co6QfTPw"
#  $ name        : chr "Flight Deck Bar & Grill"
#  $ neighborhood: chr "Southeast"
#  $ address     : chr "6730 S Las Vegas Blvd"
# ...
```

**Edit**: single-pass replacement with:

```
jsontxt2 <- gsub(sprintf("(%s)\\(([^)]+)\\)", paste(ptns, collapse = "|")),
                 "\\2", jsontxt)
```